# Unable to stylize generated RSS on <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I generated a RSS on a  tag with [the following page](https://rss.bloople.net/)

At the bottom of the page there's a tutorial on how to stylize the output, for example, it says that the title is inside a class called `feed title`, I tried to make a simple change to it but it isn't doing anything.

```css
.feed-title{
  color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="//rss.bloople.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fep00.epimg.net%2Frss%2Ftags%2Fnoticias_mas_vistas.xml&showtitle=false&type=js"></script>
```

I also tried to do it with h3 directly but it's still not working, you can find the JSFiddle of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3ht2w6go/)

Comment: `.feed-item-title a{
  color:orange;
}` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.feed-title` is the title for whole feed (which is turned off by your query parameters in the rss url with `&showtitle=false`), to target the title of each listing use `.feed-item-title`

Additionally, the `a` tag that is generated inside the title element would override your css settings for color. Try targeting the `a` tag to change the color:

```
.feed-item-title a {
  color:orange;
}
```